# Vectorizing a for-loop for cross-validation in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to speed up a script that otherwise takes days to handle larger data sets. So, is there a way to completely vectorize the following script:

```
# k-fold cross validation
df <- trees                  # a data frame 'trees' from R.
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ] # randomly shuffles the data.
k <- 10                      # Number of folds. Note k=nrow(df) in the leave-one-out cross validation.
folds <- cut(seq(from=1, to=nrow(df)), breaks=k, labels=FALSE) # creates unique numbers for k equally size folds.
df$ID <- folds               # adds fold IDs.
df[paste("pred", 1:10, sep="")] <- NA # adds multiple columns "pred1"..."pred10" to speed up the following loop.

library(mgcv)

for(i in 1:k) {    
  # looping for different models:   
  m1 <- gam(Volume ~ s(Height), data=df, subset=(ID != i)) 
  m2 <- gam(Volume ~ s(Girth), data=df, subset=(ID != i))  
  m3 <- gam(Volume ~ s(Girth) + s(Height), data=df, subset=(ID != i))  

  # looping for predictions:
  df[df$ID==i, "pred1"] <- predict(m1, df[df$ID==i, ], type="response")
  df[df$ID==i, "pred2"] <- predict(m2, df[df$ID==i, ], type="response")  
  df[df$ID==i, "pred3"] <- predict(m3, df[df$ID==i, ], type="response")   
}

# calculating residuals:
df$res1 <- with(df, Volume - pred1)
df$res2 <- with(df, Volume - pred2)    
df$res3 <- with(df, Volume - pred3)

Model <- paste("m", 1:10, sep="") # creates a vector of model names.

# creating a vector of mean-square errors (MSE):
MSE <- with(df, c(
  sum(res1^2) / nrow(df), 
  sum(res2^2) / nrow(df),
  sum(res3^2) / nrow(df)        
))

model.mse <- data.frame(Model, MSE, R2) # creates a data frame of model names, mean-square errors and coefficients of determination.
model.mse <- model.mse[order(model.mse$MSE), ] # rearranges the previous data frame in order of increasing mean-square errors.
```

I'd appreciate any help. This code takes several days if run on 30,000 different GAM models and 3 predictors. Thanks

Comment: How long does each GAM model take?  Not convinced the for loop is your problem.

Comment: Yes, profile your code and you'll see the time is spent fitting the models. Your best option is parallelization.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please help with re-writing the script into  sapply() or foreach()/doParallel format?